# Why and how to use IIFE in javascript

Tags: javascript

In this example code:

```
    (function(){
           var obj = function() {

           };

           obj.prototype.hello = function(){
                 console.log('Hello World!');
           };
    })();
```

I see a lot of libraries doing this. Why is wrapping your code in an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) a good practice? And how do I access this object outside, like jquery does?

Because if I do something like this:

```
   var test = new obj();
```

The browser displays that obj is undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid polluting outer scope. You're sure no variables are going to "get out" of it.
But yes, you do need to export it. Either using `window.obj = obj;` from inside (to make it global) or return it :

```
var obj = (function() {
  var obj = function() {};
  obj.prototype.sayHello = function() {}; 
  return obj;
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, but a lot of javascript libraries export the object without assign the IIFE to a variable. How they do it?

Comment: The first solution of my "either" : `window.jQuery = jQuery`, for example